# Logic situation on the carousel animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following situation: I'm using a carousel, and in the implementation I'm using  negative and positive margins. When you move the image to left, the margin of the previous image needs to be set to 0. I have an example [here](http://tmp.innovacionesweb.info/portfolio-single-gallery.html).

What happens is when I drag an item to the left, you can see the effect of having the other image coming on the screen. This looks ugly, so I need to solve this. How can I?

Comment: What do you want to happen?

Comment: I don't want to see the previous image flashing and comming onto the current image position, after the animation happens.

Comment: If you check the link you can see what i'm talking about.

Comment: I get what you don't want, but do you want to have happen?  And post some code in a jsfiddle or similar.

Comment: There you go http://jsfiddle.net/bV4Kr/1/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

I personally like owl carousel for these types of things.

HTML

```
<div id="slider" class="owl-carousel">
    <div><img src="http://tmp.innovacionesweb.info/img/slides/6.jpg" /></div>
    <div><img src="http://tmp.innovacionesweb.info/img/slides/7.jpg" /></div>
    <div><img src="http://tmp.innovacionesweb.info/img/slides/8.jpg" /></div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#slider").owlCarousel();
});
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/SPUbb/1/)

Comment: Actually i'm using this script, but this isn't my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is here. in your main.js file

```
$active.css( 'margin-left', 0 );
$active.prev( '.owl-item' ).css('margin-left', 400);
```

You should switch this two lines, as

```
$active.prev( '.owl-item' ).css('margin-left', 400);
$active.css( 'margin-left', 0 );
```